# App Engine remote API cannot fetch entities above specific fetch limit

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am seeing some strange performance issues with a `model.query().fetch()` operation for a specific entity kind. I can fetch up to 1,200 entities using `.fetch(limit)` but at 1,201, the fetch completely breaks and never returns. To test it out, I tried running `fetch` for increasing limits:

```
1195 fetches took 0:00:02.832000
1196 fetches took 0:00:02.798000
1197 fetches took 0:00:02.948000
1198 fetches took 0:00:02.627000
1199 fetches took 0:00:02.746000
1200 fetches took 0:00:02.657000
```

After 1200, nothing happens and I have to manually cancel the fetch operation. This behavior is consistent over many runs of the same test.

I have about 14,000 entities of the given kind and each entity has about 10 properties which are mostly *not* indexed.

The question is: Is this a bug or am I missing some insight information?

**Update:**
I can add that I see the problem in two different entity kinds now. They both break exactly at `fetch(1201)`

Comment: I should note that I can successfully read more than 1,200 entities using `fetch_page` and a loop but just using `fetch` would be easier.

Comment: Do you test this from remote api or a web handler? I remember encountered similar problem but only from remote api.

Comment: @marcadian: Indeed, it is in the remote api I am running the test to arrive at the 1,200 number but the reason I did this test was that I noticed on a backend that never returned. Maybe I should try and upload the test and see if it is exactly the same number on the backend.

Comment: @marcadian: You are completely right, it seems to be the remote api that is the problem and I feel kind of silly now :-) Anyway, if you create an answer, I will accept it immediately.

Comment: created the answer. Don't be, remote api always does some silly things ;) it can't "perfectly" imitate running console from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this problem before, this is due to limitation from using remote_api (my testing was only able to fetch 1000). The workaround is you deploy the code and test it from there.